# List deployments using apimachinery by the .spec.selector.matchLabels key

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I want to list my deployments based on a key value pair found in the `.spec.selector.matchLabels` field.

Doing so using the plain `labels` is easy, but I could not find a way to match / fetch the deployment that satisfies the condition that a certain `key=value` is present in the following section

```
spec:
  [...]
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
      process: web
      release: myrelease
```

Does not seem this can be done using the [`ListOptions`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#ListOptions)

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: `v.1.20.0`, gke

Comment: Did you try [`LIST and WATCH filtering`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#list-and-watch-filtering)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/713#issuecomment-557540936
- and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53459

You have to filter on the client side:

```
    depl, err := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments("some_namespace").List(context.Background(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    for _, item := range depl.Items {
        if item.Spec.Selector.MatchLabels["app"] == "myapp" {
            fmt.Println("found it")
        }
    }
```